# "d3.interpolators.push()" is not defined in D3.js v4.0, which function can replace it?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I write a program using D3.js and encounter an error.

```
main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I refer [D3.js Github Page](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md), `d3.interpolators.push()` is OK in D3.js v3.X, but it does not work in D3.js. How should I modify it?

Here is my code.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
d3.interpolators.push(function(a,b){
    var re = /^\$([0-9,.])+$/;
    var ma,mb;
    var f = d3.format(",.02f");

    if((ma = re.exec(a)) && (mb = re.exec(b))) { 
        a = parseFloat(ma[1]);
        b = parseFloat(mb[1]) - a;
        return function(t) {
            return "$"+ f(a+b*t);
        }
    }   
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

That method doesn't work in D3 v4.x anymore. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#interpolators-d3-interpolate):

> The d3.interpolate method no longer delegates to d3.interpolators, which has been removed; its behavior is now defined by the library.

Using D3 v4.x, you'll have to define the interpolation using [scale.interpolate](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#continuous_interpolate).

That piece of code you pasted is from [Nick Zhu's book](https://nickqizhu.github.io/d3-cookbook/src/chapter4/custom-interpolator.html), "Data Visualization with D3 Cookbook" (but the regex is wrong). So, in the following demo, I just copied Zhu's code, setting the interpolator like this:

```
var dollarScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([0, 13])
.range(["$0", "$300"])
.interpolate(
    function(a, b) {
        var re = /^\$([0-9,.]+)$/;
        var ma, mb;
        var f = d3.format(",.02f");

        if ((ma = re.exec(a)) && (mb = re.exec(b))) {
            a = parseFloat(ma[1]);
            b = parseFloat(mb[1]) - a;
            return function(t) {
                return "$" + f(a + b * t);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var dollarScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 13])
    .range(["$0", "$300"])
    .interpolate(
        function(a, b) {
            var re = /^\$([0-9,.]+)$/;
            var ma, mb;
            var f = d3.format(",.02f");

            if ((ma = re.exec(a)) && (mb = re.exec(b))) {
                a = parseFloat(ma[1]);
                b = parseFloat(mb[1]) - a;
                return function(t) {
                    return "$" + f(a + b * t);
                }
            }
        }
    );

function render(scale, selector) {
    var data = [];
    var max = scale.domain()[1];

    for (var i = 0; i < max; ++i) data.push(i);

    d3.select(selector).selectAll("div.cell")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .classed("cell", true)
        .append("span");

    d3.select(selector).selectAll("div.cell")
        .data(data)
        .exit().remove();

    d3.select(selector).selectAll("div.cell")
        .data(data)
        .style("display", "inline-block")
        .select("span")
        .text(function(d, i) {
            return scale(d);
        }); // <-N
}

render(dollarScale, "#dollar");
```

```css
.cell {
    min-width: 40px;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border: #969696 solid thin;
    padding: 5px;
}

.fixed-cell {
    min-width: 40px;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    border: #969696 solid thin;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="dollar" class="clear">
    <span>Custom Dollar Interpolation<br></span>
</div>
```